# Python TypeVar bound to a class is not compatible with bound class

Tags: python, generics, mypy, python-typing

This is a fairly contrived example, but in summary:

- I have a `Store` responsible for returning values of type `T` (a specific sub-class of `Model`
- The `Store` can contain any subclass of `Model` but allows you to register coverters such that it always returns a class of type `T`

```py
from collections.abc import Callable, Generator
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


@dataclass
class Model:
    pass


@dataclass
class EntryV1(Model):
    field: int


@dataclass
class EntryV2(Model):
    field: str


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Model)
U = TypeVar("U", bound=Model)


class Store(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, model: type[T], entries: list[Model]) -> None:
        self.model = model
        self.entries = entries
        self.converters: dict[str, Callable[[Model], T]] = {}

    def register_converter(self, old: type[U], converter: Callable[[U], T]) -> None:
        self.converters[old.__name__] = converter

    def _convert(self, entry: Model) -> T:
        if isinstance(entry, self.model):
            return entry
        else:
            converter = self.converters[entry.__class__.__name__]
            return converter(entry)

    def get(self, idx: int) -> T:
        return self._convert(self.entries[idx])

    def get_all(self) -> Generator[T, None, None]:
        return (self._convert(entry) for entry in self.entries)


store = Store(EntryV2, [EntryV1(field=1), EntryV2(field="2")])
store.register_converter(EntryV1, lambda entry: EntryV2(field=str(entry.field)))
print(store.get(0))
print(list(store.get_all()))
```

When run this code outputs:

```py
EntryV2(field='1')
[EntryV2(field='1'), EntryV2(field='2')]
```

The problem I have is that `mypy` isn't happy with is code despite `U` being bound to `Model`

```
file.py:32: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Callable[[U], T]", target has type "Callable[[Model], T]")  [assignment]
```

I'm using `U` in `register_converter` because I want to ensure the type of `old` is compatible with the type of `coverter`

```py
    def register_converter(self, old: type[U], converter: Callable[[U], T]) -> None:
```

---

**Edit**

Interestingly, if I pass the wrong type of converter to `register_converter` mypy is able to spot that it's incorrect and infer the relevant types (e.g. `register_converter(Entity1, converter)`

```
Argument 2 to "register_converter" of "Store" has incompatible type "Callable[[EntryV2], EntryV2]"; expected "Callable[[EntryV1], EntryV2]
```

Comment: You obviously request an unsafe situation: `Callable[[Model], T]` is a function that accepts **any** model, and you put a `Callable[[U]], T]` (for **one specific** `U <: Model` resolved from function signature) into the dictionary. You know how the dispatch works, but your type checker doesn't.

Comment: Btw, please don't use `__name__` for dispatch - `type` itself is hashable, and `__name__` doesn't have to be unique.

Comment: Thanks, I'd got my thinking muddled. I'd assumed it was fine for `Callable[[U], T]` to be more specific than `Callable[[Model], T]` but obviously that is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix to keep *mypy* happy was to change the type of `self.converters`, allowing the `Callable` to take a parameter of `Any`

```py
class Store(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, model: type[T], entries: list[Model]) -> None:
        self.model = model
        self.entries = entries
        self.converters: dict[str, Callable[[Any], T]] = {}
```

Whilst this fixes the problem, it means that we could in theory add the wrong type of `Callable` in the future. A more complicated, but type safe fix, is to create a custom dictionary class that enforces the interface:

```py
from collections import UserDict
from collections.abc import Callable, Generator
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, Generic, TypeVar


@dataclass
class Model:
    field: Any


@dataclass
class EntryV1(Model):
    field: int


@dataclass
class EntryV2(Model):
    field: str


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Model)
U = TypeVar("U", bound=Model)


class ConversionDict(UserDict[type[Model], Callable[[Any], T]]):
    def __setitem__(self, key: type[U], value: Callable[[U], T]) -> None:
        return super().__setitem__(key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key: type[U]) -> Callable[[U], T]:
        return super().__getitem__(key)


class Store(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, model: type[T], entries: list[Model]) -> None:
        self.model = model
        self.entries = entries
        self.converters: ConversionDict[T] = ConversionDict()

    def register_converter(self, old: type[U], converter: Callable[[U], T]) -> None:
        self.converters[old] = converter

    def _convert(self, entry: Model) -> T:
        if isinstance(entry, self.model):
            return entry
        else:
            converter = self.converters[entry.__class__]
            return converter(entry)
```